# Why is this recursive search returning unrelated results?

Tags: c#, wpf, recursion, search

I have a `WPF` `TreeView` which is populated with many child controls. All of them with children themselves are `TreeViewItems` and all without children are `Checkboxes`. Currently it has about 1,600 `Checkbox` children and sub-children. I also have a `Textbox` which is used to search through the tree by matching data in the `checkboxes` `Tags`.

The following code filters the `TreeView` when a key is typed into the `Textbox`. If this event is triggered when the `Textbox` is empty then a different algorithm runs which instead shows all children and collapses those which are `TreeViewItems`.

My question has two parts to it, why doesn't the filter method work properly? It is letting though results which do not satisfy the search term.

And secondly, how can I optimise the search function? It currently locks up my UI thread for a couple of seconds while the `ShowAndCollapse` algorithm appears to not.

```
// 'MainTree' is my TreeView being searched through

private void SearchTermTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

    if (textBox.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        ShowAndCollapse(MainTree);
    }
    else
    {
        Filter(MainTree, textBox.Text);
    }
}

private void ShowAndCollapse(ItemsControl parent)
{
    foreach (Control control in parent.Items)
    {
        control.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        if (control is TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
        {
            ShowAndCollapse(treeViewItem);

            treeViewItem.IsExpanded = false;
        }
    }
}

private void Filter(ItemsControl parent, string searchTerm)
{
    foreach (Control child in parent.Items)
    {
        if (child is TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
        {
            Filter(treeViewItem, searchTerm);

            if (IsEmpty(treeViewItem))
            {
                treeViewItem.IsExpanded = false;
                treeViewItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                treeViewItem.IsExpanded = true;
                treeViewItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        else if (child is CheckBox checkBox)
        {
            foreach (string term in searchTerm.ToLower().Split(' '))
            {
                if (!checkBox.Tag.ToString().ToLower().Contains(term))
                {
                    checkBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    return;
                }
            }
            checkBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Unexpected child type!");
    }
}

private bool IsEmpty(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
{
    foreach (Control item in treeViewItem.Items)
    {
        if (item.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1. I think your `return` statement inside your method `Filter` may be the problem, possible fix would be to use `break` in the if statement and move checkbox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible above the `for` loop. 2. To optimize the method, look into using `async` - `await`

Comment: Ahh - yes, that's it - Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Per website guidelines, I posted my comment as an answer as it solved your problem. Please mark it as the accepted answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote and accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think your `return` statement inside your method `Filter` may be the problem, possible fix would be to use `break` in the `if statement` and move `checkbox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible` above the for loop.
2. To optimize the method, look into using `async` - `await` or do as Abion47 suggested and do your filtering and sorting on the underlying data source.

Comment: His code doesn't seem to be doing anything that is inherently asynchronous, so I don't see how `async/await` would help all that much. (Not to mention trying to incorporate `async/await` in a recursive method is a pain in the ass.)

Comment: @Abion47 He wanted to know how to free up the UI thread (Part 2 of his question), so I suggested `async/await`

Comment: Except the bulk of his function deals with a lot of assignments to control properties, and those assignments have to run on the UI thread. To make it work, they would all have to be surrounded with `Dispatch`es, which is just going to put a lot of the work back on the UI thread anyway. To really optimize this code, he should be performing sorting and filtering on the underlying data source and then triggering a refresh of the view afterwards (which, frankly, is what he should be doing anyway).

Comment: @Abion47 Added to my answer to reflect your suggestion. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Abion47 - are you saying I should process a list of new treeview data and then delete all existing children, and re-populate it. Won't the constructing have a large impact on performance and memory if I'm dealing with over 1,600 children?

Comment: @TobySmith The whole idea of WPF is data binding. If you're doing it right, you shouldn't be manually creating nodes _at all_. And it might sound like a lot of overhead to do all that at once, but remember that property changes of a control triggers a redraw for that control anyway. At least by doing most of the logic on a separate thread with non-UI data, you limit the number of controls WPF has to work with by the time work gets handed back to the UI thread. (It's easier for WPF to dump all the UI data and start over than to iterate through every control and configure settings individually.)